# Django-piston: How can I get app_label + model_name?

Tags: python, django, django-piston

Before I was just using the build-in django serializers and it added a model field.

```
{
    pk: 1
    model: "zoo.cat"
}
```

How can I get the same model field using django-piston?

I tried fields = ('id', 'model') but that didn't work.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Added this to my model:

```
def model(self):
    return "{0}.{1}".format(self._meta.app_label, self._meta.object_name).lower()
```

And this to my BaseHandler:

```
fields = ('id', 'model')
```

Seems to work. If anybody has other solutions feel free to post them.

Comment: Given that in the django code (at ver 1.10) it is implemented a similar way, there is no more elegant solution...

Answer (score 5):

As your code for `app_label`:

```
    instance._meta.app_label
```

for `model_name`:

```
   instance.__class__.__name__
```

and with `get_model` can get model name from strings or url!

Answer (score 0):

Better use the meta `Options.label`

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/options/#label

```
MyModel._meta.label  # app_name.MyModel
MyModel._meta.label_lower  # app_name.mymodel
```

Answer (score 0):

reference:  [Alireza Savand's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5663202/7212249)

```
from django.apps import apps

def get_app_label_and_model_name(instance: object):
"""
    get_model(), which takes two pieces of information — an “app label” and “model name” — and returns the model
     which matches them.
@return: None / Model
"""
app_label = instance._meta.app_label
model_name = instance.__class__.__name__
model = apps.get_model(app_label, model_name)
return model
```

How to use?

```
model_name = get_app_label_and_model_name(pass_model_object_here)
```

and use this to get dynamic model name for queries

```
model_name = get_app_label_and_model_name(pass_model_object_here)
query_set = model_name.objects.filter() # or anything else
```